# Read JSON in PHP to create string from Date fields

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get date values from a JSON in PHP:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "start": {
        "date": "2019-12-27 21:05:28.073000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
      },
      "final": {
        "date": "2019-12-28 20:59:43.153000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My PHP code is trying to read the JSON but I guess that I do not reach the start and final sublevels.

I get an error and nothing is returned.

I am trying to get in one variable "2019-12-27 21:05:28 UTC+3" (start) and in another one "2019-12-28 20:59:43 UTC+3" (final)

```
<?php 
$json=file_get_contents("https://XXX/myjson.php");
$data =  json_decode($json);
if (count($data->data)) {
    // Open the table
    // Cycle through the array
    foreach ($data->data as $idx => $stand) {
        echo "first operation ".$stand->start."<br>";   
        echo "final operation ".$stand->final;   
    }}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your mistake of object element giving. see my code:

```
$json='{
  "data": [
    {
      "start": {
        "date": "2019-12-27 21:05:28.073000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
      },
      "final": {
        "date": "2019-12-28 20:59:43.153000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
      }
    }
  ]
}';
$data =  json_decode($json);
if (count($data->data)) {
// Open the table
// Cycle through the array
foreach ($data->data as $idx => $stand) {
    if(isset($stand->start)){
        echo "first operation ".$stand->start->date."<br>";  
    }else{
        echo "final operation ".$stand->final->date;   
    }

}}
```